# Magneto, Admin form is prepered two times

Tags: magento, layout, admin

I made a Magento Admin form before and it was ok. But with help of [this tutorial](https://blog.magestore.com/create-form-fields-in-magento-backend/) I added tabs to it. But in HTML output, I have two form tag. one of the has the content of the form and form key and the other just has the form key.

The problem is `company_Vendor_Block_Adminhtml_Vendor_Edit_Form._prepareForm()` is run two times. So it makes two form and I think, it runs two times because of this line in `vendorController.EditAction()`

```
$this->_addContent($this->getLayout()->createBlock('vendor/adminhtml_vendor_edit'))
    ->_addLeft($this->getLayout()
      ->createBlock('vendor/adminhtml_vendor_edit_tabs'));
```

when I just have  `createBlock('vendor/adminhtml_vendor_edit')` this is run only one-time but when I add the tab to left it is run two times.
How Can I Solve It?

**NOTE**: My code is Exactly the same as [the tutorial](https://blog.magestore.com/create-form-fields-in-magento-backend/).

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.
The problem was about an extra(useless) XML layout file. So `renderLayout()` make an extra form.ithe problem can be solved by removing XML file from layout or just convert

```
 $this->_addContent($this->getLayout()->createBlock('vendor/adminhtml_vendor_edit'))->_addLeft($this->getLayout()->createBlock('vendor/adminhtml_vendor_edit_tabs'));
```

TO

```
$this->_addLeft($this->getLayout()->createBlock('vendor/adminhtml_vendor_edit_tabs'));
```